# Facelets: how to pass a ui:insert value as an html attribute?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm trying to accomplish a small tweak in a Facelets/JSF environment. I know next to nothing how all of it fits together.

I have a value defined on various pages as "title"

```
<ui:define name="title">PageUID_123</ui:define>
```

On another page I am referencing this with:

```
<ui:insert name="title"/>
```

I can wrap html tags around the insert just fine, but I need to be able to output the value of "title" as an attribute of another element. My end goal is for it to render in html like this:

```
<meta name="pageid" content="PageUID_123"/>
```

If I try putting the insert tag in the content="" bit, it throws a parsing error. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a working environment in front of me, but I believe you don't want to you use `<ui:define>`, but instead you want to use `<ui:param>` and then use `${x}` or `#{x}` (or forget which or if it matters) to pull them out.

So, for you example you would have:

```
<ui:param name="title" value="PageUID_123" />
```

And then:

```
<meta name="pageid" content="${title}"/>
```

My only concern with that is that you are using include to have nice templates, i.e.

template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="pageid" content="${title}"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Inner page:

```
<html xmlns="...so many">
    <ui:param name="title" value="PageUID_123" />
    <ui:define name="content">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </ui:define>
</html>
```

And I really don't know if that will fly...

**Edit:** You may want to try `${title}` or `#{title}` just for kicks the way you're doing it now, it might Just Work.

Comment: In facelets it does not matter if you use ${x} or #{x}. They mean the same: https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#el